# Using parameters.xml to set parameters on scope ApplicationInsights.config

Tags: .net, azure-devops, connection-string

We are trying to push a ConnectionString key in `ApplicationInsights.config` `via parameters.xml`. The parameter does not do his way to the said file.

We build a webdeploy package that is then published to different environnements. All the other parameters are for the `web.config` and works as expected.
We want to replace

```
<ConnectionString> your connection string </ConnectionString>
```

tag in `ApplicationInsights.config` file through `parameter.xml` using azure DevOps release pipeline as we have connection string value different for our `Development/UAT/Production` environment.
But its not working using

```
 <parameter name="ConnectionString" defaultValue="ConnectionString" >
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" 
    scope="\\ApplicationInsights.config$"
    match="/ApplicationInsights/ConnectionString/text()">
   </parameterEntry>
  </parameter>
```

Can someone please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<parameter name="ConnectionString" defaultValue="ConnectionString" >
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" 
scope="\\ApplicationInsights.config$"
match="/*[local-name()='ApplicationInsights']/*[local-name()='ConnectionString']/text()" defaultValue="InstrumentationKey=;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/" >
```

Thanks to some helpful hints found Posted by Alex Marshall in http://mmmsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/parameterizing-applicationinsightsconfig.html

"

> it was because the *root* element itself [of
> ApplicationInsights.config] used a non-empty namespace

"

I'm using file deployment method. And Microsoft has since deprecated `*<InstrumentationKey>*` element. The parameters.xml match attribute value that worked for me to update the connection string:

```
 match="/*[local-name()='ApplicationInsights']/*[local-name()='ConnectionString']/text()"
```

**But hold on**. I found a second problem after that one.
MSDeploy or MSBuild doesn't match an empty target element with Xpath */text()* function. It also will not match a missing element. So if your source doc in the project ApplicationInsights.config file looks something like

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"><ConnectionString>InstrumentationKey=;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/</ConnectionString>
```

This you can successfully replace inner text with your *.setParammeters.xml* file or the *defaultValue=* attribute in *parameters.xml* .

Side note
I chose that string with the empty *InstrumentationKey=* not just for privacy redaction in Stackoverflow. It's because other strings such as `"<ConnectionString>;</ConnectionString>"` did match in deploy, but then caused failure in my Visual studio environment when I attempted to step through exceptions related to my own business logic. VS would complain about missing name spaces and code changes and basically forced me to quit without debugging. I removed the stub appinsights connection string and the problem went away. I'm guessing a bug with appinsights not releasing resources. But I still had a matching problem on deploy to solve.

I tried everything

```
        <ConnectionString/>
        <ConnectionString>  </ConnectionString>
        <ConnectionString><!-- nope --></ConnectionString> 
<ConnectionString><cutebutno/></ConnectionString> 
    <ConnectionString><![CDATA[]]></ConnectionString>
```

before realizing all I needed to do was remove is the GUID in the connection string, then VS is happy.